# How to check radio button in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a custom radio list with hidden input radio fields. Whenever I click on my custom radio button I want the hidden radio button to be checked. My custom radio button has a @click function and in that function I have the following code:

```
        customRadioHandler(key) {
            this.$refs[key].checked;
        }
```

The key parameter is the same as the ref in the hidden radio button. This code does not seem to check the hidden radio button. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: An obvious issue could be that you aren't setting a value. Maybe try this ```this.$refs[key].el.checked=true;``` ? And have a look what the output of ```console.log(this.$refs[key])``` is, just to make sure that reference is available

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" @click="handleFirstRadioClick" />
      test1
    </label>

    <label class="radio-2">
      <input type="radio" :checked="secondRadioValue" />
      test2
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      secondRadioValue: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleFirstRadioClick() {
      return (this.secondRadioValue = true);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Full example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-dust-hen6w?file=/src/App.vue